# My simple UILocalNotification is not firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

```
-(void)setNoti {
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"NOTI 1";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
    localNotification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitMinute;
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"nid":@"1"};
    localNotification.userInfo = dict;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Why my simple UILocalNotification is not firing?

Comment: Print the value of localNotification.fireDate is coming right or not?

Comment: you have require to  [application cancelAllLocalNotifications]; because notification is stored first value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of `AppDelegate`

```
UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationType) (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
             UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert);

UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
```

I am not sure you added or not, but if you missed this, you will never get local as well as remote notification.

Comment: but if I use presentLocalNotificationNow then didRecieveLocalNotification delegate is called.

Comment: Your method will get called as notification gets triggered, but it will be invisible. So to make it visible, you have to write above code.
Try it once and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have To Register Notification setting For Local and Remote Notification both Please Register notification setting First.